# Copy table from access table and paste into blank excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to accomplish the transfer of results from an access table into a blank Excel file that is not going to be saved. Basically I have a button on an access form that when pressed its action is going to just preview all the records in the access table in excel. This is the way the user wants it set up.

Right now I have code that will open a blank excel file but I am having troubles writing code that will copy the table from access and paste it into excel, say Cell "A1"

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Response As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Query1 As String
    Dim LTotal As String
    Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
    Dim strTable As String ' Table in access


     strTable = "tbPrintCenter05Que" 'Access table I am trying to copy
     Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     Set dbs = CurrentDb

     Excel_App.Visible = True
     Excel_App.Workbooks.Add
With Excel_App
.Columns("A:ZZ").ColumnWidth = 25
.Copy ' Getting error on this line 
.Range ("A")
.Paste
```

Comment: There needs to be a Range Object to use copy on. Your Code is trying to Copy the Excel_App, this can not work...

Comment: @GWD I am really unfamiliar with VBA could you suggest some code that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
    Dim dbs As dao.Database
    Dim Response As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Query1 As String

    Dim LTotal As String
    Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
    Dim strTable As String ' Table in access


    strTable = "tbPrintCenter05Que" 'Access Query I am trying to copy
    Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)

    Excel_App.Visible = True

    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add

    Dim rg As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Long
    ' Add the headings
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    Set rg = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
    rg.CopyFromRecordset rs

    ' make pretty
    rg.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Man, this works perfect, if only the columns were adjusted and also the headings from the access table didn't transfer over

Comment: This is also possible. I updated the code and it will transfer the headings. What do you mean with _columns were adjusted_?

Comment: Thanks, and I meant to make everything fit accordingly to display in a cell

Comment: I added code to _autofit_ the columms. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Absolutely! Man I tried giving your comment a up-vote but am unable too because my rep. inst high enough, but thanks again for all the help and quick responses!

Comment: after adding the following code to my vba I am getting a run time error 3008 that a table that I am using is already open by another user or interface and cannot be manipulated pro-grammatically? I am unsure what is causing this issue as there was not issue to this before I added the code you provided. I will post the following code above underneath my existing code. Is there anyway you can help me solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: Please create a new question because this is a different issue.

Comment: opps I am just now seeing this after I added it? Should I delete this and create a new question? How will I be sure you will be able to help and see the new question I am asking?

Comment: Link to this question but of course other users might be quicker than me. That should not be a big deal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749900/run-time-error-3006-when-trying-to-run-a-delete-query-error-is-saying-that-the

Comment: did you have a chance to look at this?

Comment: any chance you can give me a hand with this code? What I am trying to accomplish now is to perform a santy check after the new window in excel opens up perform a conditional formatting rule basically stating if Column name1 + Column name2 + Column name3 + Column name4 doesn't equal Column nameX highlight 'yellow'