# Run-Time Error 3008 when trying to run a delete query. Error is saying that the table records it is trying to delete is already open?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

This code below is giving me a runtime error stating the table is already open by another user, when I am trying to execute a delete query. It is only giving me this error on this delete query when I am trying to run it strictly through vba, but if i try to run it manually It works as it is designed too? Also, if I comment out this delete query I end up having no issues?

```
Private Sub Command27_Click()
Dim dbs As dao.Database
Dim Response As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Query1 As String
Dim LTotal As String
    Dim Excel_App As Excel.Application 'Creates Blank Excel File
    Dim strTable As String ' Table in access

LTotal = DCount("*", "tbPrintCenter03 RequestedToPrint", "Assigned= True")

 Select Case MsgBox("There are (" & LTotal & ") record(s) selected to be 
printed." & vbNewLine & " Do you wish to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, 
"Mark as Printed?")
 'If yes is Clicked
 Case vbYes
            Assigned = True 'Changes from false to True
            Assigned_User52 = fOSUserName 'Assigns their 5&2
            Assigned_Date = Date + Time 'Gets timestamp

'Updates the Global Table in SQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_UpdateMasterfrom04", acViewNormal, acEdit
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_AppendTo05Que", acViewNormal, acEdit
                DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_DeletePrinted", acViewNormal, acEdit 
''Run-Time error 3006 is happening on this line of code
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "tbPrintCenter_Main", acSaveYes 'Save and Close
            DoCmd.OpenForm ("tbPrintCenter_Main") 'Opens Form
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Reference Only
'                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext    'Goes to next record
'                   ' DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strTable = "tbPrintCenter05Que" 'Access Table I am trying to copy
    Set Excel_App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim rs As dao.Recordset
   Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)

    Excel_App.Visible = True

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
  Set wkb = Excel_App.Workbooks.Add

Dim rg As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
  ' Add the headings
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
  Next i

  Set rg = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
  rg.CopyFromRecordset rs

   ' make pretty
   rg.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "Qry_DeleteRecordsFrom05", acViewNormal, acEdit

   Response = MsgBox("Updated to an assigned user!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly) 
 'MsgBox Update Complete
 DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  Exit Sub

   'If no is clicked
    Case vbNo
     Response = MsgBox("No actions are performed!", vbInformation)
     Exit Sub
    End Select

  End Sub
```

Following the link provided you will see the code I am using bits and pieces ofr on. Any advice?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58732371/10226211

Comment: Maybe has something to do with the open form. Perhaps run Delete after form closes. BTW acSaveYes likely does not do what you expect. This does not save data, it saves design changes. Why do you close form then immediately reopen?

Comment: Not sure but I know it’s not that I switched up the code to actually close the form before kicking off any of those queries and still get the same run time error. I even tried throwing in an error handler for that error (which I never have used before), it ends up ignoring the error no issue however it’s still not kicking off the delete query?

Comment: Is this a bound form? Is a record still in edit mode when this procedure is initiated?